# Регуляр на PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите поправить регуляр, чтобы работал на PHP preg_match_all()
Паттерн такой:

```
   Название:</span><div>(.+?)</div>
```

Исходный текст:

```
<li class='catalog-list-linkedstyles'><span class='catalog-list-title'>Возможные модификации </span><ul><li class='catalog-list-item'><span>Название:</span><div>Wm's Trestles 30 Long</div></li>
```

Как должно выглядеть для PHP это регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$res = array();
preg_match_all('/Название:<\/span><div>([\n.]+?)<\/div>/m', $var, $res );
print_r( $res );
```

Comment: Спасибо!
/m что обозначает?

Comment: мультистроковый поиск